# react bootstrap button suddenly not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn reactjs with bootstrap 5 so I'm trying this code but it gives an empty screen when I run `npm start`. this started happening after I deployed the app using github pages. yesterday it was still normal. I'm using windows 10.

this is my code

App.js

```
import { Button } from "bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <Button variant="primary">button</Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I've already added the bootstrap css file in the index.html and I already have bootstrap 5.1.3 and react-bootstrap 2.2.1 in the package.json..

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

Either one of these should work.